# switch report manager URL to report server if access from Ipad

Tags: reporting-services

I want to see if it's possible to have only one URL for accessing reporting services from desktop as well as from mobile device like Ipad. Currently we have to use "reportserver" URL if accessing via Ipad. Like to have a more streamlined solution where we can distribute one URL to access reporting services web site and users can use it irrespective of weather they login through mobile device or desktop. Not sure why we need two URLs anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an IIS feature than a Reporting Services feature, but it is achievable. The following guide gives an example of solving a similar issue: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169853.aspx?URL+rewrite+for+Mobile+Cell+phone+devices

Essentially, you need to create a list of URL rewrites in your config file on the webserver that runs SSRS.